Replacing $\forall$ with a Function Symbol
Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first order language and $\exists\mathbf{x} \forall y A(\mathbf{x},y)$ be a sentence in $\mathcal{L}$, where $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ for some fixed $k$. Extend $\mathcal{L}$ with a $k$-ary function symbol $h$ as $\mathcal{L}' = \mathcal{L}\cup\{h\}$. As two sentences in the Language $\mathcal{L}'$, show that $\vDash\exists\mathbf{x} \forall y A(\mathbf{x},y)$ if and only if $\vDash \exists\mathbf{x}A(\mathbf{x},h(\mathbf{x}))$.
One direction is easy to show. Indeed, if we have $\vDash\exists\mathbf{x} \forall y A(\mathbf{x},y)$ then, just writing the definitions and choosing (informally) $y = h(x)$ will do the job. However, I am stuck to prove the other direction.

Posts of the form Do X are typically not well received here on Math SE. For one thing, they aren’t even questions (but commands). What do you know? What have you tried? What’s puzzling about this matter?

Assume that $\models\exists{\bf{x}}A({\bf{x}},h({\bf{x}}))$ and let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\mathcal{L}$-structure suct that $\mathcal{M}\models\forall{\bf{x}}\exists y\neg A({\bf{x}},y)$. Extend $\mathcal{M}$ to a $\mathcal{L'}$-structure $\mathcal{M}' $ by doing $h^{\mathcal{M'}}({\bf{x}})=y$ such that $\mathcal{M}\models\neg A({\bf{x}},h^{\mathcal{M'}}({\bf{x}}))$. Notice that this gives us a contradiction.

The general idea is fine. Can you add more details? By the way $A({\bf{x}},h^{\mathcal{M'}}({\bf{x}}))$ do not seem to be a valid sentence because it does not make sentence to put interpretation of symbols into sentences.

This common notational abuse arises when combining syntactical and semantic notions; however, the intended meaning is clear from the context. The contradiction arises because we conclude that $\mathcal{M}'\models\forall{\bf x}\neg A(x,h(x))$. But, our initial assumption states that $\exists{\bf x}A(x,h(x))$ is a tautology.

By the way, you also need axiom of choice to construct $h^{\mathfrak{M}'}$. I really don't like this abuse of notation as it may cause confusions for at least beginners.
